# LSI Cachecade Pro 2.0 with RAID10 SSD Cache?

Tags: raid, raid10, lsi, megaraid, megacli

I'm trying to add a RAID10 SSD Cache to a VD by this command:

```
[root@livecd storcli]# ./storcli64 /c0 add vd cachecade type=r10 drives=252:4,252:5,252:6,252:7 assignvds=0
Controller = 0
Status = Failure
Description = Unsupported RAID level
```

In the reference of this storcli command, it says raid10 is possible but it doesn't allow me to create a RAID10 array for a cache.

```
storcli /cx add VD cachecade|cc
            Type=[0,1,10]
            drives=[e:]s|[e:]s-x|[e:]s-x,y
            [ < WT| WB> ] [assignvds=0,1,2]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any link where you found any info on lsi + ssd problems? I am in dire need, too.

Answer (score 3):

It seems RAID1 with 4 SSDs means RAID10 in LSI's world. Here is a reply from LSI:

```
You would have to create your RAID 10 Cache Cade Volume in the BIOS and it will show as a RAID 1, but works as a RAID 10.
```

Comment: Yeah, that's ugly. But why do you need FOUR Cachecade SSDs?

Comment: For better speeds :)

Comment: That doesn't make sense. This is just read cache from SSD and *moar* doesn't necessarily mean better. There's a reason that the option for RAID 1+0 is not a mainline or obvious setting. It's not how these were designed to be used.

Comment: You can do RW caching with it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `type=10`?

I believe that you can only use CacheCade SSDs in RAID 0 or RAID 1. I'm not sure why you'd need RAID 1+0, though. The upper limit to the caching size per controller is 512GB, no?

Answer (score 0):

use 4 ssds in MSM to create 1 cachecade drivegroup, select raid 1.
There is no raid 10 option, however, the created drivegroup will appear to be 2x of single ssd size, and write back by default. I strongly believe it is indeed raid 10.
p.s. you can also create 2 or more cachecade drivegroup, with ssd of different sizes, might be a better solution.