# LSI CacheCade Pro 2.0 with four SSD cache?

Tags: raid, lsi, megaraid

I'm trying to configure CacheCode Pro 2.0 on a LSI 9260CV-8i SAS RAID controller with four SATA SSDs. I've been running CacheCade with two SATA 400GB SSDs with no problems for a while. The CacheCade drive group was configured with two SATA 400GB SSDs in RAID1. When I added two additional SATA SSDs to the backplane, CacheCade (or the MegaRAID BIOS Configuration Utility) did not let me add the two new SSDs to the existing CacheCade drive group. I had to create a new CacheCade drive group also configured as RAID1. So, now I have two CacheCade RAID1 drive groups, each with two 400GB SATA SSDs, and each associated with the same virtual drive comprised of four SAD hard disks in RAID10.

The RAID volume seems to be working fine, but I have no idea what CacheCade is doing with two RAID1 SSD-based drive groups. Is CacheCade effectively configured as RAID10 - meaning two striped RAID1 drive groups? If not, how are the four SSDs configured? I can't find any documentation describing this scenario. The closest I found was [LSI Cachecade Pro 2.0 with RAID10 SSD Cache?](https://serverfault.com/questions/560688/lsi-cachecade-pro-2-0-with-raid10-ssd-cache) Can someone point me to authoritative documentation on this?

Below are some screenshots from the MegaRAID BIOS Configuration Utility and the MegaRAID Storage Manager software.

Please help.

[MegaRAID BIOS Configuration Utility Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj4ja.jpg)

[CacheCade Drive Group 0 Configuration - MegaRAID Storage Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zVk4.jpg)

[CacheCade Drive Group 1 Configuration - MegaRAID Storage Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTyRz.jpg)

[SAS Virtual Drive Configuration - MegaRAID Storage Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BZYf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In your position, I would disassociate the CacheCade VDs from the HDD VDs, delete all CacheCade VDs and recreate one RAID10 CacheCade VD with 4xSSD and then associate it with the HDD VDs.

Regards,
Martin